# How to write a C struct pointer wrapper which respects constness

Tags: c++, c

I'm working in C++ but using some C APIs which work by passing pointers to structs. In order to use the data inside these structs in C++ code, I'm writing a C++ class for each struct. for example if I have a C struct like

```
struct cStruct {
  int32_t data;
};
```

then I wrap it with something like:

```
class CppWrapper {
  public:
    CppWrapper(cStruct* structData) : m_structData(structData) {}

    // These are the interface the user will deal with
    int data() const {return m_structData->data;}
    void setData(int data) {m_structData->data = data;}

  private:
    cStruct* m_structData = nullptr;
};
```

which can easily be used like

```
cStruct* s = some_c_function();
CppWrapper w(s);
w.setData(5);
```

However, if I have a C funtion which returns a `const cStruct*` then I can't use `CppWrapper` and would have to make a separate wrapper which takes a `const cStruct*` as an constructor argument, stores a `const cStruct*` and doesn't contain the editing functions like `setData()`.

Is there any way to generically write a wrapper which can adapt to const or non-const pointers and maintain that constness?

Comment: Two questions: (1) What is the purpose of the wrapper - rather than just using the struct directly, and (2) are you expected to delete the struct returned by the API once you are done with it?

Comment: (1) The wrapper provides mainly accessor functions in a consistent way (rather than just free functions taking a pointer like a C API). Also it allows nice type conversions in the C++ layer; for example the C struct may have two `float` members which you want to provide as a `std::pair`. (2) You are not expected to delete the struct, no. That would be handled by the C library. This is simply a non-owning wrapper.

Comment: Directly accessing the struct members is nice and consistent, getters and setters don't improve anything IMHO. Accessing two members as a `std::pair` is a bit more compelling, but I'm not sure it's worth all the hassle just for that benefit.

Answer (score 0):

## Initial solution

The solution I ended up with was templating the wrapper on the type of the struct so that I can have an instance of the template which only works with const pointers It looks something like

```
template<typename StructType = cStruct>
class Wrapper
{
  public:
    Wrapper(StructType* structData) : m_structData(structData) {}

    // These are the interface the user will deal with
    int data() const {return m_structData->data;}
    void setData(int data) {m_structData->data = data;}

  private:
    StructType* m_structData = nullptr;
};
```

I gave the default argument of the template type the struct type as both a form of documentation and to reduce typeing in some common cases.

This can be used in code by simply doing

```
cStruct* myCArray = some_c_function();
auto wrapper = WrapperType<>(myCArray)

const cStruct* myConstCArray = some_const_c_function();
auto constWrapper = WrapperType<const cStruct>(myConstCArray);
```

To help further, I defined a `make_wrapper()` function defined as

```
template <template <typename> class WrapperType, typename StructType>
WrapperType<StructType> make_wrapper(StructType* structData)
{
  return WrapperType<StructType>(structData);
}
```

so that you can do

```
cStruct* myCArray = some_c_function();
auto wrapper = make_wrapper(myCArray)

const cStruct* myConstCArray = some_const_c_function();
auto constWrapper = make_wrapper(myConstCArray);
```

and so `make_wrapper()` becomes the universal interface.

Based on this, it is possible to use the Wrapper interface

```
wrapper.setData(42);
std::cout << wrapper.data() << std::endl;
```

and calling

```
constWrapper.setData(42);
```

gives an appropriate error like `assignment of member ‘cStruct::data’ in read-only object`.

## Allow conversion to `const`

In order to allow a `Wrapper<cStruct>` to be converted to a `Wrapper<const cStruct>` (but not the other way round) it is necessary to introduce a set of constructors and `operator=` overloads. These constructors should only be available in the `const` version of the class.

This is doable with some use of `std::enable_if` along with `std::is_const` and `std::remove_const`. It's not the neatest since it requires a dummy parameter to the constructor but it gets the job done.

These declarations must be placed in the class definition of `Wrapper`.

```
template <typename OtherT,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<const OtherT, StructType>::value>::type>
Wrapper(const Wrapper<OtherT>& nonConstOther)
  : m_structData(nonConstOther.m_structData) {}

template <typename Dummy = StructType,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<Dummy>::value>::type>
Wrapper<StructType> operator=(const Wrapper<typename std::remove_const<StructType>::type>& nonConstOther)
  { m_structData = nonConstOther.m_structData; }
friend class Wrapper<typename std::add_const<StructType>::type>;
```

*Thanks to Jonathan Wakely for the tip for the better constructor version using `std::is_same`.*

## Reusable interface

It would be quite common to need more than one of these in your C++ interface in order to interact with lots of other C structs. Therefore, I think it would be useful to factor out the common code (particularly that template-heavy stuff) so that the boilerplate is reduced.

I ended up creating a base class `observer_ptr_wrapper` (named to be similar to [the proposed observer_ptr](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf)) which holds the innards:

```
template<typename PointerType>
class observer_ptr_wrapper
{
public:
  observer_ptr_wrapper(PointerType* structData) : m_structData(structData) {}

  using NonConstPointerType = typename std::remove_const<PointerType>::type;
  friend class observer_ptr_wrapper<typename std::add_const<PointerType>::type>;

  template <typename OtherT,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<const OtherT, PointerType>::value>::type>
  observer_ptr_wrapper(const observer_ptr_wrapper<OtherT>& nonConstOther)
    : m_structData(nonConstOther.m_structData) {}

  template <typename Dummy = PointerType,
            typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<Dummy>::value>::type>
  observer_ptr_wrapper<PointerType> operator=(const observer_ptr_wrapper<typename std::remove_const<PointerType>::type>& nonConstOther)
    {m_structData = nonConstOther.m_structData;}

protected:
  PointerType* m_structData = nullptr;
};
```

Which can then be inherited from with:

```
template <typename StructType = const cStruct>
class cStructWrapper : public observer_ptr_wrapper<StructType>
{
public: 
  // These are the interface the user will deal with
  int data() const {return m_structData->data;}
  void setData(int data) {m_structData->data = data;}

//This is the boilerplate
public: using observer_ptr_wrapper<StructType>::observer_ptr_wrapper;
private: using observer_ptr_wrapper<StructType>::m_structData;
};
```

so that the overall boilerplate is reduced to just those two lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, `const Wrapper<cStruct>` is not `Wrapper<const cStruct>` and you are at least missing assignment (and copy) from `Wrapper<cStruct>` to `Wrapper<const cStruct>`.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the next thing that I would want to implement. I just need to work out the template magic to make it work generically.

Comment: You can get rid of the Dummy parameter in the SFINAE that allows const conversions: `template <typename OtherT, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<const OtherT, StructType>::value>::type>
  observer_ptr_wrapper(const observer_ptr_wrapper<OtherT>& nonConstOther)`

Answer (score 0):

you can create multiple constructors :

```
class CppWrapper {
  public:
    CppWrapper(cStruct* structData) : m_structData(structData), mc_structData(nullptr) {}
    CppWrapper(const cStruct* structData_c) : mc_structData(structData) {}
    // These are the interface the user will deal with
    int data() const {return m_structData->data;}
    void setData(int data) {m_structData->data = data;}

  private:
    cStruct* m_structData = nullptr;
    const cStruct* mc_structData;

};
```

Comment: That could work if there were suitable checks inside each of the interface functions. And perhaps as well if in the non-const constructor, `mc_structData` was set to point at `m_structdata`.

Answer (score 0):

What about starting with something altogether simpler?  A combination of template specialisation and inheritance goes a long way to giving what you want.

```
#include <iostream>

struct cStruct {
  int32_t data;
};

template <typename T> class CppWrapper;

// const version implements const member functions (getters)
template <>
class CppWrapper<const cStruct *> {
 public:
  CppWrapper(const cStruct * d) : d(d) {}

  int data() const { return d->data; }

 private:
  const cStruct * d;
};

// non-const version implements non-const member functions (setters)
template <>
class CppWrapper<cStruct *> : public CppWrapper<const cStruct *> {
 public:
  CppWrapper(cStruct * d) : CppWrapper<const cStruct *>(d), d(d) {}

  void setData(int data) { d->data = data; }

 private:
  cStruct * d;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  struct cStruct s;
  s.data = 0;

  CppWrapper<const cStruct *> a{&s};
  CppWrapper<cStruct *> b{&s};

  const CppWrapper<const cStruct *> c{&s};
  const CppWrapper<cStruct *> d{&s};

  // Getters...
  std::cout << "a.data() = " << c.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b.data() = " << d.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c.data() = " << c.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d.data() = " << d.data() << std::endl;

  // Setters...
  std::cout << "Setting data to 1" << std::endl;
  // a.setData(1);  // Won't compile, as you would hope
  b.setData(1);
  // c.setData(1);  // Won't compile, as you would hope
  // d.setData(1);  // Won't compile, as you would hope

  // Getters (again)
  std::cout << "a.data() = " << c.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b.data() = " << d.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c.data() = " << c.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d.data() = " << d.data() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The non-const version inherits all the const version's 'getter' functions, and extends it with the 'setters'. There's not that much boilerplate code; possibly not enough to warrant a more generic solution?